# zend won't recognize registered namespace

Tags: zend-framework, zend-autoloader

I'm using the Zend Standard Autoloader. It's registering one namespace, but it won't register the other. This is my code:

```
$zflib = $_SERVER['SERVER_ROOT'].'/classes/Zend_Framework_2/2.3.2/library';
require_once($zflib.'/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php');
$loader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array('autoregister_zf' => true));
// Library
$loader->registerNamespace('VProd',$_SERVER['SERVER_ROOT'].'/classes/VProd');
// Dealer Library
$loader->registerNamespace('Dealers', $_SERVER['SERVER_ROOT'].'/dealers/classes');
$loader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
$loader->register();
```

I then have basic setup like this in the dealers/classes directory:

Model.php

```
<?php

namespace Dealers\Models;

class Model {
    /**
     * The table this model uses
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table;
}
```

Coop Model:

```
<?php

namespace Dealers\Models\Coop;

use Dealers\Models\Model;

class Coop extends Model {
    /**
     * The table this model uses
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'coop';

    public static function testing()
    {
        return 'testing';
    }
}
```

In my application I'm including that config file BEFORE anything else.

coop.php

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['SERVER_ROOT'].'/security/config.php');

use Dealers\Model\Coop;
echo CoopBalance::testing();
```

I'm getting this error message:

> Fatal error: Class 'Dealers\Models\Model' not found in
>   \www\dealers\classes\coop\Coop.php on line 7

Which is where this line is in my Coop Model:

```
class Coop extends Model
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's the path (not just filename) to your class files?

Comment: Model: dealers/classes/Model.php
Coop Model: dealers/classes/coop/Coop.php (there will be others related to coop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ZF2 standard autoloader is a [PSR-0 compliant](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) autoloader. So your classes should be at `dealers/classes/Dealers/Models/Model.php` and `dealers/classes/Dealers/Models/Coop/Coop.php` (case sensitive) to get autoloaded properly (each 'part' of the namespace should be a folder).

Also, if at all possible I'd recommend using Composer to install ZF2 (or whichever components you're using). Then you wouldn't need to configure the autoloader yourself at all.

Comment: This system is already implemented so I can't do much editing since so many of their internal websites rely heavily on it. But thank you for that explanation!